# Fetch 1 image of 4 from another table using id as foriegn key from a table in codeigniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, nested

**I have two database tables. One for product info and other of the multiple images of the same product.
The thing i am trying to do is fetch all the info of the products and fetch one image at a time with it. I am building this project in codeigniter.**

> the query i am running goes like this

```
public function fetchdata()
    {

            $query=$this->db->select('*')
            ->from('selleritem')
            ->get();
            return $query->result();

}
    public function fetchimage()
    {
        $image=$this->db->distinct()
        ->select('*')
            ->from('selleritemimages')
            ->limit('1')
            ->get();
            return $image->result();
    }
```

> the output it gives is like all the images are sent to the view.
>
> please assist on making it easier to work with tried all the logics i
>   could but failed.

Comment: You want for each product info one image isn't it ? - if so pls post your controller code too because this looks completely wrong ;)

Comment: You want to fetch specific image of product or any one of them..?

Comment: i want to fetch info of all products and one mage of each product from another table for images corresponding to PID(product id). @sintakonte

Comment: my controller code is:-                                                                             
             public function index()
 {

  $this->load->model('fetchindex');
  $fetch=$this->fetchindex->fetch();
  $image=$this->fetchindex->fetchimage();
  

  $this->load->view('welcome_message',['fetch'=>$fetch,'image'=>$image]);
  
 }